# (python) function minimisation with PyMC holding one argument fixed

Tags: python, pymc, minimization

Hello all PYTHON users (especially the PyMC ones).

the problem:
I want to perform function minimisation using MCMC. My function L (which happens to be a -logGaussian) has N variables. I want to loop over one variable and holding it fixed, sample L over the remaining N-1 free variables. The purpose of this is to build the "profile" of L along one specific direction in its multidimensional parameter space. Hence, am **not** interested in the posterior distribution of the N-1 free parameters, but rather in the samples of the N-1 parameters and the corresponding values of the function L.

my implementation (schematically - no MWE):

```
import numpy as np
from pymc import Uniform, MCMC

# the quantity I will be looping on
J_array = np.linspace(15,18,10)

# the other N-1 parameters which need to be sampled
a = Uniform('a', lower=0, upper=10)
b = Uniform('b', lower=0, upper=10)
c = Uniform('c', lower=0, upper=10)
r = Uniform('r', lower=0, upper=10)

for J in J_array:
    # (must all parents be distributed according to a distribution
    # or is there a way to avoid this?)
    # I define the looped-over variable as a uniformly-distributed
    # observed quantity (right?)
    J_i = Uniform('J', lower=15, upper=18, value=J, observed=True)
    
    # the deterministic L the values of which I'm interested in
    @deterministic
    def L(J=J_i, a=a, b=b, c=c, r=r):
        return LL(J, a, b, c, r)
    
    M = MCMC(L)
```

I also tried

```
J = Uniform('r', lower=15, upper=18, value=J_array, observed=True)
@deterministic
def L(J=J, a=a, b=b, c=c, r=r):
    return LL(J, a, b, c, r)
    
M = MCMC(L)
```

and

```
def model(J):
    a = Uniform('a', lower=0, upper=10)
    b = Uniform('b', lower=0, upper=10)
    c = Uniform('c', lower=0, upper=10)
    r = Uniform('r', lower=0, upper=10)
    J_i = Uniform('r', lower=15, upper=18, value=J, observed=True)
    
    @deterministic
    def L(J=J_i, a=a, b=b, c=c, r=r):
        return LL(J, a, b, c, r)

    return L

for J in J_array:
    M = MCMC(model(J))
```

In all cases, `LL` is the instance of a class which has a `__call__` method, and in all cases I get a

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

I'm not interested in repeated sampling (because I don't care about posteriors).
After `M = MCMC(loglike)` I would just like to sample in a Markovian fashion L( J | a, b, c, r) for every `J`, by drawing (say) 1000 values of the variables `a, b, c, r`. From this, I would then extract the minimum L value and it's corresponding parameters.

## UPDATE

The correct form of the code is:

```
def model(J):
    a = Uniform('a', lower=0, upper=5)
    b = Uniform('b', lower=0, upper=5)
    c = Uniform('c', lower=0, upper=5)
    r = Uniform('r', lower=0, upper=5)
    
    @deterministic
    def loglike(J=J, a=a, b=b, c=c, r=r):
        return LL(a, b, J, r, c)
    
    return locals()
    
for J in J_array:
    M = MCMC(model(J))
```

which shows that not all parents of a `pymc` variable must be pymc-distributed variable.

I still don't know if this is the smartest way of performing function minimisation by means of MCMC sampling. I would like to hear any comment of readers who disagree or simply have suggestions.
Thank you very much to all users.